# Answered question under Unanswered tab

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Check the below image, The tab which is active is **Unanswered** but questions with answer is also listed.

Probably a bug

[image]

Answer (score 7):

It's not a bug.

If you look, you'll see that those answers are either scored 0 or less. If you look at the side, you'll see that it says

> questions with no upvoted or accepted answers

Since those questions don't have upvoted answers, they remain in the Unanswered tab.

Blame the rest on caching.